# MVC 4 | Export the View to Excel with formatting to fit on A4 size

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application for which i need to design a report such that it has header and footer on every page and the contents in the middle section (between header and footer). 
The content section may vary to some few lines, which may vary on different pages.
My requirement is

1. I want to export the data / view to the excel with header and footer.
2. Also i need to format the document to be adjustable to A4 size paper only.

Let me know if someone has the solution for the above question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and it was hard to find a free open source library that is still maintained and support lot of functionality.

I've found a library called NPOI, the .Net version of POI JAVA library and very happy with what it offers.

https://npoi.codeplex.com/

This gives you lot of control over how the excel file is created. By `View`, if you mean the html file, I'm not sure if you can export that using this library. But I am certain that you can export data with this.

I've create extension methods for each type of entity that I want to export to excel. You can do a more complex extension method and use `Reflection` and `DataAnnotations` within the entity to generate the required columns for the excel file.